# SpotifySDK﹕ Got error 8 using SpotifySdkAndroid-1.0.0-beta3

Tags: android, spotify

Getting below error while playing 
sample song spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V

```
I/SpotifySDK﹕ Got notification: Became active playing device

I/SpotifySdkDemo﹕ Player event: became active

**E/SpotifySDK﹕ Got error 8**
```

Sample Code

```
  Spotify spotify = new Spotify(access_token);
  mPlayer = spotify.getPlayer(this, "My Company Name", this, 
      new Player.InitializationObserver() {
          @Override
          public void onInitialized() {
              mPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(SpotifyAuthActivityDemo.this);
              mPlayer.addPlayerNotificationCallback(SpotifyAuthActivityDemo.this);
              mPlayer.play("spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V");
          }

          @Override
          public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
              Log.e("MainActivity", "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 8 is "Login failed: Bad credentials". Check your login credentials and handle the appropriate login events in the SDK accordingly.